# Как изменить view пагинации в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, pagination

есть дата провайдер:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Shop::find()->where(['status'=>1, 'men' => 1])->orderBy('id DESC'),
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 10,
            ],
        ]);
```

сейчас он подставляет пагинацию автоматически сразу после последней статьи, как поменять ее местоположение ?

Comment: например через css?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Наверно мне нужно view поменять а не positionom ставить

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от того как ты это выводишь во вьюхе.
например если через виджет GridView:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'layout' => "{summary}\n{items}\n{pager}",
'columns' => [
    'id',
    'name',
    // ...
],
]) ?>
```

редактируй в макете `'layout'` расположение `pager`, так как тебе необходимо.

Если `ListView` [смотри тут](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-baselistview.html#$layout-detail);

Либо ты можешь воспользоваться виджетом `LinkPager`, и расположить его где угодно.

```
 <?php echo LinkPager::widget([
        'pagination' => $dataProvider->pagination,
    ]); ?>
```